# Check SUM of registers on SELECT mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I Have 2 tables with this info

tabsell

```
SellId |      ItemId     
1      |        2      
2      |        3   
3      |        2     
4      |        3    
5      |        4
```

tabitens (this table have alot of columns but i put only 2 for a example)

```
ItenId |      ItemName     
2      |        Iten2      
3      |        Iten3   
4      |        Iten4     
5      |        Iten5
```

What im try to do is

Select FROM tabitens only if the SUM of the ItenId on tabsell is < 2

What is the right way to make the query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `LEFT JOIN` on this so `Items` with no records (*not been sold*) on tableSell will also be shown on the list.

```
SELECT  a.ItemID, a.ItemName
FROM    tblItem a
        LEFT JOIN tblSell b
            ON a.ItemID = b.ItemID
GROUP BY a.ItemID, a.ItemName
HAVING COUNT(b.SellId) < 2
```

`COUNT` is recommended to use than `SUM` because `COUNT` adds the number of rows while `SUM` adds the *value* of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select ItenId, ItenName
  From tabsell inner join tabitens
 Group b ItenId, ItenName
Having count(1) < 2
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is more favorable to use than `INNER JOIN` because if items don't have records on table sell, it will be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```sql
SELECT itemid 
FROM tabsell 
GROUP BE itemid  
HAVING count(*) < 2
```